# Formal proof of language accepted by a specific CFG

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Let $G=(V,\Sigma,R,S)$ be the grammar given by the following rules:
\begin{align}
&S \to aS \mid B \\
&B \to abBc \mid \epsilon
\end{align}

Please provide a formal proof for the following claim:
$$
L(G) = \{ a^i (ab)^j c^j : i,j \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$

Comment: They aren't equal $L(G) = \{ a^i (ab)^j c^j|i,j\geq0\}$, which is different from $L$. You probably misread something about the definition of $G$ or $L$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out my mistake in the original post.

Comment: This question is modified from an assignment; I changed the grammar and L to learn the idea of proving this type of question.

Comment: I know how to do S->uSw|$\epsilon$, S->XY, and S->X|Y. However, I don't know how to approach  S->S|X

Comment: Is $S\rightarrow S|X$ different from $S\rightarrow Y, Y\rightarrow Y|X$? How?

Comment: Y->Y|X has Y-> X where X is non-terminal and $X\neq Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L = \{ a^i (ab)^j c^j : i,j \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The proof consists of two steps:

- $L \subseteq L(G)$.
- $L(G) \subseteq L$.

The first step proceeds by direct construction: we show how to produce each word in $L$ using the grammar. In order to produce the word $a^i (ab)^j c^j$, we first apply $i$ times the rule $S \to aS$, then once the rule $S \to B$, then $j$ times the rule $B \to abBc$, then once the rule $B \to \epsilon$. Formally, we could prove that this works by induction.

For the second step, we first prove by induction that all words generated by $B$ are of the form $(ab)^jc^j$. We show that by induction on the length of a production starting at $B$. If the first step is $B \Rightarrow \epsilon$ then we generate $\epsilon$. Otherwise, the first step is $B \Rightarrow abBc$. By induction, the $B$ on the right produces a word of the form $(ab)^jc^j$, and overall the produced word is $(ab)^{j+1}c^{j+1}$, which is of the same form.

We can now prove the required claim by induction on the length of a production starting at $S$. If the first step is $S \Rightarrow B$, then the preceding paragraph shows that the generated word is of the form $(ab)^jc^j$. Otherwise, the first step is $S \Rightarrow aS$. By induction, the $S$ on the right generates a word of the form $a^i (ab)^j c^j$, and overall the produced word is $a^{i+1} (ab)^j c^j$, which is of the required form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you give the inductive hypothesis for the induction in the first step? Many thanks.

Comment: If $B \Rightarrow^n w$ then $w \in \{ (ab)^j c^j : j \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: I think your I.H is for the second step.

Comment: Right, this is the IH for the second step. You'll have to work out the first step on your own. I'm not going to write a full-fledged answer with all details.

Comment: I finished a complete proof under you guide, many thanks.